# How to solve fortran runtime error: bad repeat count in item 2 of list input

Tags: fortran, runtime-error, gfortran

Here is my main code:

```
!* ... READ PROBLEM TITLE
      READ  (KGET1,*)  TITLE(1)
      WRITE (KPUT1,*) 'TITLE(1)= ',TITLE(1)
      WRITE (KPUT1,*)

!... READ PROBLEM UNITS
      READ  (KGET1,*)  UNITS(1)
      WRITE (KPUT1,*) 'UNITS(1)= ',UNITS(1)
      WRITE (KPUT1,*)

!... READ PROBLEM OTHER
      READ  (KGET1,*)  OTHER(1)
      WRITE (KPUT1,*) 'OTHER(1)= ',OTHER(1)
      WRITE (KPUT1,*)

!... READ OPTIONAL INPUT INDICATOR
      READ  (KGET1,*)   OPTION
      WRITE (KPUT1,*) 'READ OPTIONAL INPUT?',OPTION
      WRITE (KPUT1,*)
!....................................................................
!*** END MINIMAL INPUT ***
!....................................................................

!*** BEGIN OPTIONAL INPUT ***
!....................................................................

!... READ OPTIONAL INPUT OR SET DEFAULT VALUES
      IF (OPTION) THEN

!......... READ DIAGNOSTIC REVIEW, REPORT, SAMPLE, WARNING ENABLERS
            READ  (KGET1,*) REVIEW, REPORT, SAMPLE, WARN    !<-- line 579
            WRITE (KPUT1,*) 'REVIEW=',REVIEW
            WRITE (KPUT1,*) 'REPORT=',REPORT
            WRITE (KPUT1,*) 'SAMPLE=',SAMPLE
            WRITE (KPUT1,*) 'WARN=',WARN
```

And here is my input file text

```
blah-blah-blah   
 ENGLISH 
 blah-blah-blah
 .TRUE.                                     OPTION
 .TRUE.    .FALSE.    .FALSE.    .TRUE.     REVIEW,REPORT,SAMPLE,WARN
```

I am getting this error

```
At line 579 of file bob.f95 (unit=11, file ='cal.i1'
Fortran runtime error: bad repeat count in item 2 of list input
```

I think it has something to do with the list because it reads the other values in the file. Maybe it is reading .TRUE. wrong? Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Is there a `*` character somewhere in the input file?  If so - it has special meaning.

Comment: No there are no * characters in the input file. My KGET1 = 11, which is the unit being called. I had my unit as 5 and 6 before but fixed those because they mean something else. This list error is troubling.

Comment: Without complete compilable source it is difficult to say more.

Comment: Input lis line oriented: one line per read statement.